# Clustering WS-AT Web service

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing, wsat

does anyone knows if it is possible to cluster WS-AT web services using JBoss?

Thanks in advance

Leandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to cluster web services that use WS-AT using JBoss.
At least using JBoss EAP 6.4.